# Finding the simplest logically equivalent formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, predicate-logic

For the below python statement:
`[redacted]`  I am meant to find the simplest logically equivalent formula. That is...remove a logical connectives such as not, and, or while still making the formula logically equivalent as the one given.

So I plugged in the above formula to a python file and gave it some values (range from -5 to 5). This is the code:

```
print("------default question---------")

def range1(start, end):
        return range(start, end+1)

for y in range1 (-5,5):
    if ~([redacted]):
        print(y)
    else:
        print("{} and {}".format("Missed", y))
```

And I got these numbers:

```
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

The first thing that I did from here was to remove the NOT symbol and flip all the logical operators.

So this is the transformed code:

```
print("------opposite of question---------")

def range1(start, end):
        return range(start, end+1)

for y in range1 (-5,5):
    if ([redacted])):
        print(y)
    else:
        print("{} {}".format("Missed", y))
```

which gave me the result:

```
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
Missed 1
Missed 2
Missed 3
Missed 4
Missed 5
```

I've tried various test cases but to no avail, I was getting more confused from this small problem.

Would love if someone could point me in the right direction. Cheers :)

Comment: "if ~ (y > 1 or (y <= 1 & y % 2 == 0))" translates as 
\begin{align*}
\neg (y>1 \vee (y \leq 1 \wedge \text{y is even}))\\
y\leq 1 \wedge \neg(y\leq1 \wedge \text{y is even})\\
y\leq 1 \wedge(y> 1 \vee \text{y is odd})\\
(y\leq 1 \wedge y> 1) \vee (y\leq 1 \wedge \text{y is odd})\\
\emptyset \vee (y\leq 1 \wedge  \text{y is odd})\\
y\leq 1 \wedge  \text{y is odd}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hey @RahulMadhavan I understand what you did, however in line 5 where you translated `(y≤1∧y>1)∨(y≤1∧y is odd)` into `∅∨(y≤1∧y is odd)` is what I got confused with. Which rule / formula did you use?

Comment: $y≤1∧y>1$ means $y$ is less than 1 and $y$ is greater than 1. These are disjoint events and cannot happen together. Therefore $y≤1∧y>1 = \varnothing$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the original statement, you are checking the numbers `y <= 1` for divisibility by 2: `y <= 1 & y % 2 == 0` - you can not just change the inequality to `y > 1` and leave the divisibility check like this `y > 1 & y % 2 != 0`, because that is now checking other numbers. Not to mention, that `&` should also be a `|` by your logic, but that still doesn't fix the problem of checking other numbers.

Comment: Noted! that clears things up. Cheers David